# Question about the underbrace in combination with the array

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, arrays

I'm trying to use the `\underbrace` option, and I kind of managed to make it work with the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
\left(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2\right)^T G \left(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2\right) =   &  \Lambda_2^T \underbrace{\Lambda_1^T G \Lambda_1} \Lambda_2 & = \Lambda_2^T G \Lambda_2 = G \\ 
 & = G & {}
\end{array} 
\end{equation}
```

However, I'm not really happy about the spacing between the different signs of the cells, because it is not how my other "normal" equations look like:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can make this look better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular instance, you don't need an `array` since it messes with the vertical alignment of your equation number. Instead, use `\underbrace` the way it's intended to be used:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    \left(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2\right)^T G \left(\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2\right) =  &  \Lambda_2^T \underbrace{\Lambda_1^T G \Lambda_1} \Lambda_2 & = \Lambda_2^T G \Lambda_2 = G \\ 
      & = G & {}
  \end{array} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  (\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2)^T G (\Lambda_1 \Lambda_2) = \Lambda_2^T \underbrace{\Lambda_1^T G \Lambda_1}_{{}=G} \Lambda_2 = \Lambda_2^T G \Lambda_2 = G
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to have a larger script in the `\underbrace`, use `\textstyle`.

If you must have some form of alignment, you could use a `r@{}c@{}l` column specification in your `array` and supplement the equations with surrounding empty groups `{}` to achieve proper spacing.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you! Instead of `textstyle`, I've used `displaystyle`. Also, in what scenario is it better to use an array?

Comment: @Hunter: Whenever you want a specific horizontal alignment and stack stuff.